# returns the first n of list

Tags: list, scheme

How to return the first `n` elements of a list? Here's what I have:

```
(define returns(lambda (list n)
 (cond ((null? list) '())
 (((!= (0) n) (- n 1)) (car list) (cons (car list) (returns (cdr list) n)))
        (else '()))))
```

Examples:

```
(returns '(5 4 5 2 1) 2)
(5 4)

(returns '(5 4 5 2 1) 3)
(5 4 5)
```

Comment: Welcome to SE! Please format your question more nicely and readable. What is it that you want to accomplish? Want to define a procedure that returns the first N elements in a list?

Comment: Please _format_ your code before posting it, I fixed it this time, but really, you should be more careful if you want people to help you.

Answer (score 12):

You're asking for the [`take`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/list..rkt%29._take%29%29) procedure:

```
(define returns take)

(returns '(5 4 5 2 1) 2)
=> (5 4)

(returns '(5 4 5 2 1) 3)
=> (5 4 5)
```

This looks like homework, so I guess you have to implement it from scratch. Some hints, fill-in the blanks:

```
(define returns
  (lambda (lst n)
    (if <???>                     ; if n is zero
        <???>                     ; return the empty list
        (cons <???>               ; otherwise cons the first element of the list
              (returns <???>      ; advance the recursion over the list
                       <???>))))) ; subtract 1 from n
```

Don't forget to test it!

Comment: R5RS I need to be. take: undefined; cannot reference undefined identifier

Comment: @New then implement it yourself, as hinted above. I won't do it because this looks like a homework, it's up to you.

Comment: (define (returne list n)
        (take list n))

Comment: You can't use `take` in R5RS, implement `returns` from scratch as hinted above.